# Python - How might I get rid of the decimal places on a number like "2345.67"

Tags: python

I would like to separate the decimal from the numbers so I have something like

```
2345.67
k = 2345
d = .67
```

Answer (score 9):

```
>>> divmod(2345.67, 1.)
(2345.0, 0.6700000000000728)
```

**EDIT:**

If negative numbers "matter":

```
if k < 0:
  k += 1
  d -= 1
```

Comment: @Haidro: Probably because I didn't assign to `k` and `d`.

Comment: print(divmod(-2345.67, 1.)); ==> (**-2346.0**, 0.32999999999992724)

Comment: I'd be deeply saddened if that was the reason

Comment: This is quite brilliant, using `divmod`.

Comment: @Artur Whether that matters or not depends on what behaviour you expect for negative numbers..!

Comment: @ChrisTaylor: No human being would interpret "separate the decimal from the number" to mean that result unless they already had that result and were trying to rationalize it.

Comment: @ChadMiller Or they had ever studied math.

Comment: @ChrisTaylor I have a math degree. If the question specifically mentioned remainders, you would have a point, but that's not what the OP said.

Answer (score 2):

```
number = 2345.67
k, d = str(number).split('.')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import math
n = 2345.67
k = math.floor(n)
d = (n - k) if k > 0 else (k - n)
print k, d
```

Comment: It completely breaks on negative numbers.

Answer (score 0):

There are several methods of doing this, but here is some easy ones.

Convert it to a string, split it, and assign the values back:

```
>>> n = 2345.67
>>> n_string = str(n)
>>> k, d = n_string.split('.')
>>> k, d = int(k), int(d)
>>> print(k, d)
(2345, 67)
```

Note that with this, you changed `.67` to `67`.

Alternatively, substract the values and get them:

```
>>> k = math.floor(n)
>>> d = abs(n)-abs(k)
>>> print(k, d)
2345 0.6700000000000728
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: The second one breaks on negative numbers.

Answer (score 0):

if you really need to avoid floating point math:

```
from decimal import Decimal
num = Decimal('2345.67')
sign, digits, exponent = num.as_tuple()

sign = (-1)**sign


k, d = sign*int(''.join(str(d) for d in digits[:exponent])), sign*int(''.join(str(d) for d in digits[exponent:]))

# optional: d *= 10**exponent if you really need it to turn it back into a float
```

(I realize this is more complicated than just splitting on the string but `Decimal` is good to know about if you need to do any actual math with this)